# How to Convert Group of Labels to Textboxes Dynamically In reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Is there anyway to convert group of specific labels to textbox

I tried NPM Package **react-inline-input-edit**

here is the Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-inline-input-edit

but it's only provide one textbox edit on click. Any way to click on edit button
generate multiple labels into textboxes

Comment: you can always this kind of case with ternary operator to show or hide some code with a condition, you nedd to specify some code to help you out a little bit, to understand better why are you traying to do!

Comment: Please try and include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can better understand what it is that you're trying to do.